# Named parameters in python sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to build a parameterized query for sqlite, and I know I can do this:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test ("name", "age") VALUES (:some_name, :some_age);', 
            {"some_name": "Joe", "some_age":45})
```

However, I have a dictionary that has spaces in the keys. I can't find any information on the legal tokens for the named parameters, and can't seem to come up with any combination that works. Am I out of luck -- no spaces in the named parameters and no way to escape them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter names must be valid identifiers; consisting only of letters, digits and underscores.

So, no, spaces are not going to work here.

The Python delegates parameter handling to the SQLite C API here, and it is this API that sets these limits; see [*Binding Values To Prepared Statements*](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

> VVV represents an alphanumeric identifier

Comment: Thanks - not really a big deal I guess to use an OrderedDict and replace the spaces...